# Spring maven libraries

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

I would like to know why some of the libraries are not released during a normal release cycle. For example, from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/

while spring-core have 3.0.3-RELEASE, spring-remoting and spring-jmx were released only in 2.0.8. Can someone tell me what this would mean? I agree that if there are no changes in the component say spring-jmx then they don't have to release it, but since 90% of the world uses Maven for dependency management can they not just re-release the same libs (of spring-remoting and spring-jmx?)

I ask this because I declare my deps like,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and I would prefer supplying one spring.version instead of keeping version numbers upto date for all components?

The four libraries of interest to me are `spring-dao, spring-support, spring-jmx, spring-remoting`

Comment: According to maven definitive guide unless you specify the version with [] or () (or [) or (] ), maven searches for the version you wrote on the Pom and if it doesn't find it it goes for another. I guess you could add your version dependency like (,${spring.version}]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`spring-remoting` and `spring-jmx` became a part of `spring-context`, so newer versions are released with `spring-context`.

Comment: Thanks @axtavt, Can I ask you what happened to spring-dao and support? Basically how do I find out how/where/if these projects have merged? (I ask this because the next time I have a similar problem I want to know how to find this ....)

Comment: This might help, although the details are sparse: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-in-3-modules-build

Comment: Also note that spring-webmvc depends on spring-context. So if you depend on spring-webmvc you will get the former spring-remoting included by default.

Comment: Are you sure that `spring-remoting` was merged into `spring-context`? The docu references classes like `org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean`, but this class cannot be found in `spring-context`. E.g. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html